# Javascript calendar not working

Tags: asp.net, javascript

My JavaScript calender is working in IE but it is not working in Mozilla.

My code:

```
  <table>
   <tr style="height: 5px;">
    <td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtBorderedDate" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxMandatory" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="FieldButton_bg" style="height: 5px;"> 
     <a onclick="javascript:showCalendarControl(ctl00_SaralConetentPlaceHolder_txtBorderedDate);" href="#">
       <img src="../Images/iconCalendar.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; vertical-align: bottom;" border="0" />
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error in IE?

Comment: No..I am not getting any error

Comment: You shouldn't be using the JavaScript pseudo-protocol!

Comment: Have you thought about the fact that this code really tells us nothing about the JS Calendar you are using except the manner of invocation. I would've thought that you'd have learned something from the previous question.

Comment: how does your JS calendar work? this question isn't clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the problem (you should post some more of your code), but you shouldn't hard code the ID of the controls in ASP.NET. Also, I think some quotes might be missing in the showCalendarControl() call.

Replace this:

```
<a onclick=
 "javascript:showCalendarControl(ctl00_SaralConetentPlaceHolder_txtBorderedDate);" ...
```

With this:

```
<a onclick="showCalendarControl('<%= txtBorderedDate.ClientID %>');" ...
```

Some of the parent controls of txtBorderedDate might get rendered differently in different borders, thus resulting in a different client-side ID of the textbox control.

Comment: +1 but I doubt this is reason... JS based Calendars are complex dynamic structures that have a lot of dynamically created elements. In this case, he seems to be passing the ID of the textbox which will receive the selected value of the calendar.